# SOAP call in nodejs without wsdl

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, soap

I have a NodeJS application, from where I'm supposed to use web service (that support only soap) through soap calls.

The biggest problem is, that the Web Service doesn't have a WSDL api description anywhere. So my question is, how could I call servoce methods with NodeJS, use Soap without WSDL.
I have seen some solutions like use of require module.Installed the same(npm i require).Able to set headers and other options but dont know how to call the methods.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know a method to call and types and a number of parameters and return value without WSDL?

SOAP is a self-descriptive protocol that's why you can (and you should) use WSDL to get the whole description of what a certain service provides to you. All SOAP services normally have a rule that you can add '?wsdl' (or something similar) at the end of a service url to get WSDL.

You can try to construct a HTTP request by hand but it's worthless cause you will spend a lot of time to implement all method calls and to take into account types of parameters, their restrictions and structure and so on.